# What is the most efficient flight shape for a plane shooting at a target?

Tags: geometry

If you imagine a plane like an X-wing in Star Wars Battlefront 2 which can only fire whilst moving forward shooting at a target, it can only shoot for a finite amount of its time as it must move towards and then turn around. We can call the maximum radius of curvature of the plane $x$ and the speed of the plane $v$. [Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4yanK.jpg) (red = bullets).

One such example of this motion is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNsuw.jpg). The plane can shoot for a length $d$ in a total circuit of length $2d + 4x$, meaning the efficiency is maximised when as $d$ approaches infinity, which would yield an efficiency of 0.5.

Are there any better patterns you could take to have a higher efficiency? This could be done in 2d or 3d.

Answer (score 1):

You can show $0.5$ is the upper bound. Suppose the circuit is traversed in time $T=T_1+T_2$, and that total time $T_1$ is spent moving directly toward the target. Over the time spent moving toward the target, the distance to the target decreases by exactly $vT_1$. Therefore, over the ramaining time, the distance to the target must increase by exactly $vT_1$ However, the maximum change in distance over this time is $vT_2$. This constraint is unsatisfiable if $T_2<T_1$, so $T_1\le T_2$ for any path. You have found an example that saturates this inequality, so it is optimal.